# Putting image at the right without affecting the layout

Tags: html, css

I am trying to insert a picture on the right without affecting the text which is in the middle. I tried to put the picture in the front using `z-index` in hope that it doesn't affect the layout below. But in fact, the text "footer" is not in the screen center anymore.

```
    <div style="z-index:99;display:inline-block;float:right">
        <img src="https://www.xing.com/img/custom/events/events_files/e/6/3/765539/square96/Apfel_klein.jpg?1443451610">
    </div>

    <p align="center">footer</p>
    <p align="center">footer</p>
```

This is how the page looked at the beginning:
https://jsfiddle.net/eucysjp6/

This is after I tried to insert the picture:
https://jsfiddle.net/eucysjp6/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eucysjp6/2/

Comment: You should add relative position to the div, and absolute to the image. The rest is play with margins/padding.

Comment: just goggle a bit about css position property. If you want an html element out of the normal flow you have position absolute to do it

Comment: yes, it makes sense. I already tried `position:absolute` in an earlier test, but it turns out that there is another problem in the website (see below), which vanished because of my abstraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position the image absolutely and the table relatively to put the image in the bottom right corner without affecting the text:

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eucysjp6/3/)**

```
img {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
table {
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. It seems to work on my abstract example [where I thought that it represents my real website]; but when I tried to implement it on the real website, it doesn't work. I have made a new abstraction which reproduces the problem I encountered with the real website: https://jsfiddle.net/eucysjp6/4/ . I cannot understand why the picture has such a weird position.

Comment: Where should the picture be?

Comment: On the right, exactly like it is seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/eucysjp6/2/ . I just set the `right:50;bottom:50` because the picture had left my screen on the left side. Weird...